# Delete data between two lines inclusive

Tags: bash, shell, unix

What would be the best way to search and delete data between two lines of text, including the first line but not the second.

String 1: `SECTION - PAY 500` - to be deleted

*data to be deleted, random lines of text*

String 2: `SECTION - Pay 400` - stay

This is word document that is around 3000 pages, but I also have a text version to work with. Where would I begin writing a bash script for such a task?

example of the file content:

```
text 
SECTION - PAY 500    (to be deleted)
text                 (to be deleted)
SECTION - Pay 400
text 
SECTION - PAY 500    (to be deleted)
text                 (to be deleted)
SECTION - Pay 400
text
```

After deletion, this should be the result

```
text 
SECTION - Pay 400
text
SECTION - Pay 400
text
```

Comment: Assuming you're looking to delete numerous blocks from your 3000 page doc, can you give us a few more examples. How many blocks to you expect to delete? Will there every be ambiguity between the text in the section markers, i.e. `SECTION - PAY 5000` ? Good luck.

Comment: `sed` would be my go to here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution with the standard `sed`:

```
sed "/$START/,/$END/ { /$END/"'!'" d; }"
```

This mean that for the range starting at `/$START/` and ending at `/$END/` action `{ /$END/! d; }` will be done, which does `d` (delete) for all lines that are not `/$END/`.

`"'!'"` is just weird, but the only way to escape `!` symbol from bash expansion.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could parse the file line by line quite quickly. What you are rtying to archieve doesn't seem to be too complicated to realize.

```
copy=true
while read line; do
    if [ $copy ]; then
        if [[ "$line" == "SECTION - PAY 500"* ]]; then copy=; continue; fi
        echo "$line" >> outputfile
    else
        if [[ "$line" == "SECTION - Pay 400"* ]]; then copy=true; fi
    fi
done < inputfile
```

And by doing so we even have something like a little turing machine now!

Answer (score 0):

Another (less weird ;)) standard sed solution:
`sed "/$END/ p; /$START/,/$END/ d;"`

Side note: certain `sed` versions also support in-place editing of files, if needed.

And a full fledged bash script:

```sh
#! /bin/bash

if [ "x$1" = "x-r" ]
then
    regex=1
    shift
else
    regex=0
fi

if [ $# -lt 2 ]
then
    echo "Usage: del.sh [-r] start end"
    exit 1
fi

start="$1"
end="$2"

function matches
{
    [[ ( regex -eq 1 && "$1" =~ $2 ) || ( regex -eq 0 && "$1" == "$2" ) ]]
}

del=0
while read line
do
    # end marker, must be printed
    if matches "$line" "$end"
    then
        del=0
    fi
    # start marker, must be deleted
    if matches "$line" "$start"
    then
        del=1
    fi
    if [ $del -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo "$line"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution : Try this way

**Inputfile.txt**

```
text 
SECTION - PAY 500    
text                 
SECTION - Pay 400
text 
SECTION - PAY 500   
text                 
SECTION - Pay 400
text
```

**Code**

```
awk '/500/{print;getline;next}1' Inputfile.txt | sed '/500/d'
```

**Output**

```
text 
SECTION - Pay 400
text 
SECTION - Pay 400
text
```